# mvn install not creating jar files in the local repository

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have a `pom.xml` file for my `util` direction, inside my project:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </parent>

       <artifactId>util</artifactId>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>Util</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
         ...
         <other things here>
       </project>
```

When I execute `mvn clean install`, it works fine. However, when I try to use that `util` dependency I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project helloworld: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myapp.app:helloworld:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.myapp.app:util:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
```

Looking into `~/.m2/repository/` I don't see a `util` directory. Why is that happening? How can I have `maven` to install those packages in the local repository?

```
************************** Last 15 lines *******************
[INFO] Copying jdom-1.0.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/jdom-1.0.jar
[INFO] Copying httpclient-4.2.6.jar to /myapp/util/target/dependency/httpclient-4.2.6.jar
[INFO] Copying maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/maven-scm-provider-svn-commons-1.4.jar
[INFO] Copying aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.34.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/aws-java-sdk-cloudsearch-1.9.34.jar
[INFO] Copying jdom2-2.0.4.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/jdom2-2.0.4.jar
[INFO] Copying poi-scratchpad-3.12-beta1.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/poi-scratchpad-3.12-beta1.jar
[INFO] Copying aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.34.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/aws-java-sdk-cognitoidentity-1.9.34.jar
[INFO] Copying elasticsearch-1.4.2.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/elasticsearch-1.4.2.jar
[INFO] Copying c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar to myapp/util/target/dependency/c3p0-0.9.1.1.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ util ---
[INFO] Installing myapp/util/target/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to ~/.m2/repository/com/myapp/app/util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing myapp/util/pom.xml to ~/.m2/repository/com/myapp/app/util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 6.855 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-22T11:32:59-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/465M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: <groupId> is missing.

Comment: <groupId> is taken from parent, so it is not missing

Comment: @krzyk so I should also have a group id for the dependency?

Comment: @philippe please correct the name of the package, yoou write that it is `utils` but in the logs you provided it is `util`

Comment: @philippe <dependency> always has to have groupId (maven will scream if it doesn't), you don't need groupId in the above pom, because you inherit from parent which has groupId defined

Comment: Are there any settings for maven-install-plugin in this pom or parent pom?

Comment: @user2953113 everything is working now ... but I know there's a problem there. The only thing different I did was `mvn clean install -DskipTests -P-generateLicenses` from the `myapp` directory

Answer (score 4):

When you do `mvn clean install`, please take a look at `[INFO] Installing` line and see where it installs your package, maybe your config is wrong.

Log above  shows that the package installed correctly. 
Please show us how you define dependency to utilize in hello world.

Comment: there isn't a `[INFO] Installing` step in the logs ... However I can find `util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` in the `..util/target` directory ... how can I fix that?

Comment: It's the package phase that created the jar file in target directory. No need to fix it.

Comment: This is funny.. because there it is in your own log: Installing myapp/util/target/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to ~/.m2/repository/com/myapp/app/util/1.0-SNAPSHOT/util-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: btw, thank you @Krzysztof Krasoń the installing line showed me that i was installing to a different local repository. exact solution.